# How can I get the result value of a SQL Server stored procedure with Laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

I'm having problems getting the result of a SQL Server stored procedure using Laravel 5.4.

I'm using Laravel to call a stored procedure that inserts some values in a couple of tables and returns the ID of the new row. For simplicity let´s say that this is the stored procedure

```
procedure proc
@param1 int,
@param2 int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON

begin tran
insert into table (x,y) values (@param1, param2)

declare @id_table bigint = scope_identity()

commit

return @id_table
```

The procedure works and I know this because I have tested it in MSSQL Management Studio (and yes, I DO have to use the store procedure)

Now, I want to call this stored procedure from Laravel to store the values and get the return value. I've tried the following:

**First try:**

```
$c = DB::connection('sqlsvr')->select('exec proc ?,?', array($var1, $var2));
```

In this case the stored procedure executes sucessfully as there is a new row inserted in the table, but $c is an empty array.

**Second try:**

```
$c = DB::connection('sqlsvr')->statement('exec proc ?,?', array($var1, $var2));
```

In this case the stored procedure also executes sucessfully but then $c is a boolean value.

I don't have an Eloquen model for the inserted values since I don't own the database and I don't want to create a model only to call a stored procedure.

Would you have any idea of what can I do to get the stored procedure's return value? Thanks

Comment: Why not use an output parameter instead of the return value?

Comment: Do not use return for getting scalar values from stored procedures, use output parameters instead.

Comment: I know that I can do it with output parameters and if I can´t do it with return values I´ll have to do it with output parameters, but I am not really the database owner. There is already people using the database and the stored procedure so it won´t be ease to change them. I could create new ones but... I would like to avoid doing that. Thanks